# Class is not applying to submit button

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I m Trying to apply a class to following submit button
Code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit" class="confirm-button-submit ">
```

css :

```
.confirm-button-submit 
{
   width    : 79px;
   font      : bold 12px sans-serif;;
   color    : #000;
   background    : url("../images/confirm-btn.png") 0 -33px no-repeat;
   text-decoration : none;
   margin-top    :0px;
   text-align:center;
   border:0px;
   cursor : pointer;
   height:170px;
}


.confirm-button-submit a
{
   width    : 79px;
   font      : bold 12px sans-serif;;
   color    : #000;
   background    : url("../images/confirm-btn.png") 0 -33px no-repeat;
   text-decoration : none;
   margin-top    :0px;
   text-align:center;
   border:0px;
   cursor : pointer;
   height:170px;
}



.confirm-button-submit a:hover
{
   width    : 79px;
   font      : bold 12px sans-serif;;
   color    : #000;
   background    : url("../images/confirm-btn.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
   text-decoration : none;
   margin-top    :0px;
   text-align:center;
   border:0px;
   cursor : pointer;
   height:170px;
}
```

But its not working proper what to do

Thanks

Comment: What is not working proper once you set the class name?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you intended the CSS rule for `.confirm-button-submit` to apply, but your button does not have that class.

You'd have to use:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit" class="confirm-button-submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not have a class.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit" class='confirm-button confirm-button-submit'>
```

*edit* — well one set of problems might be that you're attempting to set CSS attributes that an `<input type='submit'>` element just doesn't support. I suspect that if you were to look at your `<input>` element in the Firebug DOM inspector you might see all your CSS classes, but you'd also see that they don't actually have any effect.